# Repeate Array when last text has been reached?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I quite new to programming and I've created this app that says a joke when the button is pressed the only problem is when it reaches the last text the app crashes because there is no more texts to be seen. I sure there is a way to start the array from the start again when the last text is reached, I'm just not sure how to do that. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView line = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line);
    Button bl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bl);

    final String[] jokes = { 
        "joke 1", "joke 2" , "joke 3" , "joke 4"     
    };

    bl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rando++;
            line.setText(jokes[rando]);

        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: this is a comment if it helps you then i post it as answer, use exception handlers and catch arrayOutBoundsException and start again..does it make sense? want a code on it? SIr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting a random number each time the button is clicked, you just need to not increment the counter before accessing your array:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView line = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line);
    Button bl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bl);

    final String[] jokes = { 
        "joke 1", "joke 2" , "joke 3" , "joke 4"     
    };

    bl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            line.setText(jokes[rando]);

        }
    });
}
```

Another alternative would be to get one random number once, store it in a field, and then increment it each time the button is clicked:

```
int rando; // store in a field in your Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView line = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line);
    Button bl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bl);

    final String[] jokes = { 
        "joke 1", "joke 2" , "joke 3" , "joke 4"     
    };
    final int jokeCount = jokes.length;
    rando = (int) (Math.random() * 4); // initialize only in onCreate

    bl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (++rando >= jokeCount) { // increment in onClick
                rando = 0;              // reset counter when needed
            }
            line.setText(jokes[rando]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was doing this but, it not very good because it contently repeats jokes you have already seen (just the way random number work), so I would like it so that when you start the app it selects a random joke and then go through them one by one. I should have specified this in the question sorry.

Comment: The second alternative should work for you then. That starts the random in one location and then cycles through the list, wrapping around at the end.

Comment: NP. I edited and added it a minute later, after the first one. Glad to help!